# AJAX sending a GET instead of a POST

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm working on Laravel and trying to send a variable to a controller using AJAX, but the request is changing to GET!

**AJAX**

```
function fetchTasks(email) {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/teamwork',
    data: {_method: 'POST', email : email},
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::any('/teamwork', 'TeamworkController@teamwork')->name('testPRoute');
```

When i change the route method to post, it shows a 405(Method Not Allowed)

When i dd($request) in my controller, this is what i get
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryNRC.png)

So, why my Ajax request doesn't work ?

**EDITED:**
I've modified my code to the following

```
function fetchTasks(email) {
   console.log(email);
   var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

   $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "teamwork",
       data: {
           _token:token,
           'email': email
        },
        contentType: "application/json",

        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
           console.log(err);
        },
        complete: function () {
             window.location.href = '{{route("testTRoute")}}';
        }
});
```

}

It's still sending an empty GET request. Output from console is the following:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

Comment: How do you call ajax? Any Button press or menu link (a tag)? I doubt you use ajax with a link. If so, it will not work.

Comment: I validate if the user email exists in the database first. If so, i call the function with "fetchtasks( );". I think it's working because as you can see in the image it changes the route to "/teamwork"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of debugging, i have found that my problem was with the routing. I had two routes, GET and POST with the same name. That's why it was always sending a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ajax [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) you should use **type** param instead **method**.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this?

```
$.ajax({
   headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
   url:'teamwork' ,
   type:'post',
   data: { email : email},
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(result){console.log(result);}
  });
```

Route

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/teamwork', 'TeamworkController@teamwork')->name('testPRoute');
```

Comment: Same issue nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send 'email' as a route parameter but don't want to show it in browser's address bar, you can do it as below.

Sending data through a form

At you blade.php

```
<form action="{{route('testPRoute')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <!--
    Set your email name or variable in input's value attribute. Like
    <input type="text" name="email" value="email">
    or 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="{{$email}}">
     or -->
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="email">
    <button type="submit">Go to Route</button>
</form>
```

At your Web.php

```
Route::post('/teamwork', 'TeamworkController@teamwork')->name('testPRoute');
```

At your Controller

```
public function teamwork(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->email;
    return $email;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if i can or how i can use a form to send it. I don't have a form for user login. Instead i'm using google login like this example https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/